# Populate dynamic created controls with random number

Tags: c#, asp.net

OK. Couple a days ago I asked a Question how to generate random numbers like 100, 1000, 10.000 etc without using arrays and my question got deleted because maybe the answer wasnt so obvious. I got that with simple solution, but now I have another problem. What I'm trying here is to populate every dynamic created Label with different random numbers. I dont know of what reason every 10 lines always get the same numbers. Here's the code behind that I'm trying to get work:

```
protected void btnExample1Random_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Making the controls visible
    this.Master.FindControl("Div1").Visible = true;        

    //Generating the random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Label randomTask = new Label();
        Label emptyTask = new Label();
        TextBox userInputTextBox = new TextBox();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int caseInt = rnd.Next(1, 4), myNum = 0;
        switch (caseInt)
        {
            case 1:
                caseInt = 100;
                myNum = rnd.Next(1, 100);
                break;
            case 2:
                caseInt = 1000;
                myNum = rnd.Next(1, 1000);
                break;
            case 3:
                caseInt = 10000;
                myNum = rnd.Next(1, 10000);
                break;
        }

        //Forming the controls
        randomTask.ID = "lbl" + i.ToString();
        randomTask.Text = caseInt.ToString() + " - " + myNum.ToString() + " ";
        userInputTextBox.ID = "box" + i.ToString();
        emptyTask.ID = "check" + i.ToString();

        //Adding the controls into the placeholder
        phTutorijal1.Controls.Add(randomTask);
        phTutorijal1.Controls.Add(userInputTextBox);
        phTutorijal1.Controls.Add(emptyTask);
        phTutorijal1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    }

    //Separating the next created controls into new line
    phTutorijal1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
}
```

There's a bug in this code that I cant find it. Every 10 lines generated into the placeholder are with the same numbers. What did I miss here?

**Update:** Michael Liu spotted where my bug is: I needed to put the `Random rnd = new Random();` outside the for cycle

Comment: Move `Random rnd = new Random();` before (outside) the `for` loop.

Comment: Aaaaah, thanks Michael, didnt saw that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the same number because you're creating the random instance in the loop. Hence it will be initializedn with the same seed derived from time. You just need to declare it  outside of the loop:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int caseInt = rnd.Next(1, 4), myNum = 0;
```

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx):

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same
>   seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated. ...